# Do Until Loop checking for duplicates wont stop looping

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do a Do Until Loop to check for duplicates in my combo box. It runs the loop but it never stops looping.

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim flavors As Integer = flavorsComboBox.Items.Count

    Do Until (i < flavors - 1)
        If flavors = flavorsComboBox.Items.Count Then
            MessageBox.Show("Flavor Already Exists!", "Error")
        Else
            flavorsComboBox.Items.Add(flavorsComboBox.Text)
        End If
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition of the loop looks at the `i` variable and the `flavors` variable:

```
Do Until (i < flavors - 1)
```

But those variables don't ever change at any point in the body of the loop:

```
   If flavors = flavorsComboBox.Items.Count Then
        MessageBox.Show("Flavor Already Exists!", "Error")
    Else
        flavorsComboBox.Items.Add(flavorsComboBox.Text)
    End If
```

You need to add code to change one or both of those variables. But that's still the hard way to do this. Just use the `Distinct()` method:

```
Dim items = flavorsComboBox.Items.Distinct().ToArray()
flavorsComboBox.Items.Clear()
flavorsComboBox.Items.AddRange(items)
```

Comment: Didn't think of doing it that way, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple do until loop

```
Dim i as integer = 0
Dim flavors as Integer = 10

do until (i > flavors -1)
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString())

    i = i +1
loop
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

In your code:

```
do until (i < flavors - 1)
```

if i = 0 and flavors is the Count -1 when is 0 greater than count, to enter the condition of the loop.

The next omission is that you never change the value of condition variable of looping, to have an accurate evaluation of the condition to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If AddDistinct(flavorsComboBox, "test") Then
            MsgBox("Item did not exist, so it was added.")
        Else
            MsgBox("Item already existed, so it was not added.")
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Function AddDistinct(cboBox As ComboBox, value As Object) As Boolean
        If cboBox.Items.IndexOf(value) = -1 Then cboBox.Items.Add(value) : Return True
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not resetting the value of flavors

Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim flavors As Integer = flavorsComboBox.Items.Count

Do Until (i < flavors - 1)
    If flavors = flavorsComboBox.Items.Count Then
        MessageBox.Show("Flavor Already Exists!", "Error")
    Else
        flavorsComboBox.Items.Add(flavorsComboBox.Text)
        flavors = flavorsComboBox.Items.Count
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Now I don't get any Error messages when I test for that.

Comment: How does this solve the problem?  Unless the _flavorsComboBox_ has less than 2 items in it, you will get an endless loop of message boxes since _i_ never changes and is always 0.